# Icon display on google chrome bar

Tags: google-chrome

I just open my google chrome and see that there is an user icon on the top left corner of my google chrome (next to tabs). I don't know why it there but it freaks me out. I tried to find a way to shut it off. If anyone know how to shut if off, please let me know. It freaks me out.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you have another user added on your chrome account. Go to `Menu -> Settings -> People` and check if there are other users. If there is another user chrome automatically adds a user profile picture to each browser user. You can remove the other users and take that off.